# "Missing Value Keyword" in tDbOutput Talent

Tags: etl, talend

I am building a job to insert data into a table from another table. I have added lookup for the destination table to ensure that insertion only happens if the record does not exist.

Approach I am using is:

`tDbInput (Main) --> tDbInput (Lookup) --> tmap --> replicate --> tFileOutputDelimited, tDbOutput (both at the same time)`

While running the job I getting error saying, "Missing Values Keyword".
I ensured that the not null columns are being inserted and that the column name matches with the columns in the destination table in tmap output.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the schema is replicated from the tmap to the t_DBOutput.
Also check the settings of the t_DBOutput.
Is it set on `insert data` ?

You can also check the generated code of the t_DBOutput to look for problems.

Comment: It has been set to insert data. It seems to return some null values in the output file for columns which have to be not null. The tmap expression has been set to obtain those values but somehow it is giving null.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the settings of the t_DBOutput. Basic and advanced settings. And a screenshot of the job design